# Concurrent solution for dining philosophers problem failing

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

## Question

Five silent philosophers sit at a round table with bowls of spaghetti. Forks are placed between each pair of adjacent philosophers.

Each philosopher must alternately think and eat. However, a philosopher can only eat spaghetti when they have both left and right forks. Each fork can be held by only one philosopher and so a philosopher can use the fork only if it is not being used by another philosopher. After an individual philosopher finishes eating, they need to put down both forks so that the forks become available to others. A philosopher can take the fork on their right or the one on their left as they become available, but cannot start eating before getting both forks.

Eating is not limited by the remaining amounts of spaghetti or stomach space; an infinite supply and an infinite demand are assumed.

Design a discipline of behaviour (a concurrent algorithm) such that no philosopher will starve; i.e., each can forever continue to alternate between eating and thinking, assuming that no philosopher can know when others may want to eat or think.

The philosophers' ids are numbered from 0 to 4 in a clockwise order. Implement the function void wantsToEat(philosopher, pickLeftFork, pickRightFork, eat, putLeftFork, putRightFork) where:

- philosopher is the id of the philosopher who wants to eat.
- pickLeftFork and pickRightFork are functions you can call to pick the corresponding forks of that philosopher.
- eat is a function you can call to let the philosopher eat once he has picked both forks.
- putLeftFork and putRightFork are functions you can call to put down the corresponding forks of that philosopher.
- The philosophers are assumed to be thinking as long as they are not asking to eat (the function is not being called with their number).
  Five threads, each representing a philosopher, will simultaneously use one object of your class to simulate the process. The function may be called for the same philosopher more than once, even before the last call ends.

## Approach

I have created two synchronized method to pick and put down forks. *wantToEat* waits untill both forks are picked and at the end it put down forks.
Deadlock would be avoided as I am not holding one fork and waiting other to be available. *Hold and wait* will not be applicable.

Correct me if I am wrong, if a method is synchronized then:

- Two threads can't execute the same method at a time.
- Method would become atomic(i.e. the thread executing the method would complete executing the method before other thread can start executing ) and results of the method would be visible to other threads(i.e updates in boolean array would be visible to other threads).

The code is failing for few testcases. Can't think of a reason what could be the issue during concurrent execution.

## Code

```
class DiningPhilosophers {

    private volatile boolean [] forks;

    private int getRightFork(int index){
        return (index+1)%5;
    }

    public DiningPhilosophers() {
        forks = new boolean[5];
    }

    private synchronized boolean pickForks(int index){
        int leftForkIndex = index;
        int rightForkIndex = getRightFork(index);
        if(!forks[leftForkIndex] && !forks[rightForkIndex]){
            forks[leftForkIndex] = true;
            forks[rightForkIndex] = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private synchronized void putDownForks(int index){
        int leftForkIndex = index;
        int rightForkIndex = getRightFork(index);
        if(forks[leftForkIndex] && forks[rightForkIndex] ){
            forks[leftForkIndex] = false;
            forks[rightForkIndex] = false;
        }
    }

    // call the run() method of any runnable to execute its code
    public void wantsToEat(int philosopher,
                           Runnable pickLeftFork,
                           Runnable pickRightFork,
                           Runnable eat,
                           Runnable putLeftFork,
                           Runnable putRightFork) throws InterruptedException {

            while(!pickForks(philosopher)){
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }

            pickLeftFork.run();
            pickRightFork.run();
            eat.run();
            putLeftFork.run();
            putRightFork.run();
            putDownForks(philosopher);
    }
}
```

Comment: Re, "The function may be called _for the same philosopher_ more than once, even before the last call ends." Wait! What? That makes no sense. What is it supposed to mean if the framework calls `wantsToEat(N,...)` when philosopher `N` currently _is_ eating in some different thread? How is the "philosopher" supposed to behave in that case? IMO you should ask your instructor for clarification. It's possible that maybe the question got mangled in translation somewhere.

Comment: Re, "The code is failing for [a] few test cases..." Failing how? What does the framework tell you? Do those test cases have names? Is there any description of what they are testing for?

Comment: The framework takes 'n' as an input where n is the number of times each philosopher will call the function. For n=10 sometimes it passes sometimes it fails. I don't have access of code which is being used for calling *wantsToEat* or the runnables passed in the method.

Comment: If say philosopher 0 is eating in some thread and *wantsToEat* is called again then it is expected that philosopher 0 completes eating, puts down the forks and waits till  he/she gets chance to eat again.

Comment: My answer—now deleted—was worse than wrong because the method that I proposed to force a naively written `DiningPhilosophers` class into deadlock would have _incorrectly_ failed your implementation. I said I would delay the return from the `pickLeftFork` and `pickRightFork` functions until all five philosophers had tried to claim at least one fork. But, your implementation guarantees that at least three of the philosophers would not even _try_ to claim a fork until the other two have eaten. I never would have allowed _any_ of your philosophers to have even one fork...

Comment: ...Is it just me? or might the person who wrote the actual test harness have made a similar mistake? **Q:** Did any rule forbid your philosophers from communicating with each other? They kind-of _do_ communicate through the shared `forks[]` array. IMO, that doesn't go against the spirit of the dining philosophers because each philosopher only "talks" to his immediate neighbors, and they only talk about who is holding the fork. But maybe your use of the `forks[]` array violates some dodgy assumption (e.g., like _my_ dodgy assumption) that's built-in to the test harness.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but, Your code assumes a ring of exactly five philosophers. Five _is_ the traditional number, but a simulation could be constructed for any number of philosophers greater than one. Are you certain that your code will only ever be tested on a ring of five?